# Proof that $\mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 2$ is connected by contradiction with clopen sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Question:

> By the following argument, show that $\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 2$ is connected:

> Suppose, if possible, there is proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is clopen. Let $x\in Y$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$. Let $\ell$ be the line joining $x$ and $y$. Show that $\ell\cap Y$ is both open and closed in $\ell$ and hence obtain a contradiction.

*(Source: Intermediate Mathematical Analysis, R.D.Bhatt, Ex. 6.3.1)*

I have proved that $Y\cap \ell$ is closed by using the fact that $Y$ and $\ell$ are closed, but I have no idea on proof of $Y\cap l$ being open.

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: You are confusing closedness in $\mathbb R^{n}$ with closedness in $\ell$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n}$ so $Y \cap \ell$ is open in the relative topology of $\ell$. $Y$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{n}$ so $Y \cap \ell$ is closed in the relative topology of $\ell$. $\ell$ is a connected space in the relative topology and this gives a contradiction.